# How to detect ringer switch state in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, openal, avaudiosession

I configured my audio session for kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound for an app which plays music with AVAudioPlayer. But problem is app also plays effects with OpenAL. I want music to play always (also in background) but OpenAL sound effects only if mute switch not muted.

Answer (score 2):

There is no documented way of doing it, but you can try [this project](https://github.com/Rich2k/RBDMuteSwitch). It is an open source project that claims it can detect if your mute switch state changes.

Answer (score 0):

One iOS-5-compatible trick (which the source that shabzco posted uses) is to play an audio recording of a known length. If the completion handler fires sooner than expected then the mute switch is probably on.